# lpr on HP print truncated document

Tags: php, pdf, lpr

i'm new here and first of all sorry for my bad english.
This is my problem:
I generate a PDF document using FPDF (the rsulting document is correct, i check twice) and send it to a network printer using lpr command:

```
.....
$pdf->Output('stampe/lipari.pdf', 'F');

//specify the pdf I want to print
$file = 'stampe/lipari.pdf';

//Change PrinterName to the name of the printer you set up in CUPS
$cmd = "lpr -Plipari -o landscape -o fit-to-page ";
//append any files you'd like to print to the end of the command
$cmd .= $file.' 2> output';
exec($cmd);
```

The command return no errors and the document is printed but is always truncated by 5cm.
I try several things like print with specified margins but nothing affect the result.
The only visible result is when i print mirroring the document: mirrored but truncated on the other side by 5cm.

Thanks for replays

EDIT: I discover my client will return only in september and cause I can tray only "on site" I can't test right now any solution. I appreciate anyway some help.

Comment: Which OS/distribution is this?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it. Is Debian. At the moment i can't be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you omit the `-o fit-to-page` parameter? Can you also try it with pure `lp` syntax?

Try changing the command to `lp -d lipari -o landscape` and check the result.

Comment: For the first time I try without any -o command and the result was the same.
Never try simple lp....sure I will but not now cause I can only try on site but my client will return in september as I edited. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cause the project was suspended for while i find the solution just now.

Actually the problem wheren't in the lp/lpr command. The problem was the printer driver.
We reinstall HPLIP and set the correct driver...just that.

Anyway thanks for the answers.